# NodeJS Mongodb compare data in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have data in MongoDB structured like this

```
[
{
    "users": [
        "5dd13dac47b4c85e382c6e27",
        "5dce9f6d95f4ee0017be3c2c"
    ],
    "created_at": "2019-11-20T11:22:19.167Z",
    "_id": "5dd5224d76cf581424e1bb83",
    "name": "Fast Weight Loss",
    "program": [
        {
            "breakfast": [
                "3x Eggs",
                "2x Bread",
                "Cup of Milk"
            ],
            "lunch": [
                "1/4 Chicken breast"
            ],
            "dinner": [
                "1x Apple"
            ],
            "snack": [],
            "_id": "5dd5224d76cf581424e1bb84"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "users": [
        "5dd168eea514847564f04a74",
        "5dd010a1dfa846001742e913"
    ],
    "created_at": "2019-11-20T11:30:22.316Z",
    "_id": "5dd5259bcdb7af35f09e6f9e",
    "name": "30 Days Weight Loss",
    "program": [
        {
            "breakfast": [
                "3x Eggs"
            ],
            "lunch": [],
            "dinner": [],
            "snack": [],
            "_id": "5dd5259bcdb7af35f09e6f9f"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

]

I want to send a post request to my nodeJS server with a user if the userid exists in my users array this

```
    "users": [
    "5dd13dac47b4c85e382c6e27",
    "5dce9f6d95f4ee0017be3c2c"
],
```

or this

```
        "users": [
        "5dd168eea514847564f04a74",
        "5dd010a1dfa846001742e913"
    ],
```

it send the "program" array back as response here is what I have been trying:

```
users.post("/dietData", (req, res) => {
  var id = req.body.userID;

  DietProgram.find()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.users.contains(id)) {
        res.json(user.program);
      } else {
        res.send("User Weight Data Does not Exsist");
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send("error: " + err);
    });
});
```

but I got an error that apparently I can't use contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `users` property is an Array, I think you are trying to use `include()`you can use it like this `users.includes(id)`